# Why insert into statement is executed after divide by zero exception thrown

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query.

```
IF Object_id('tempdb..#test_tran') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #test_tran 

CREATE TABLE #test_tran 
  ( 
     id   INT, 
     name VARCHAR(255) 
  ) 

GO

---------------------------------------- 

BEGIN TRAN 

  DECLARE @a FLOAT = 1 / 0.0 

  INSERT INTO #test_tran VALUES (1, 'Red') 

COMMIT TRAN 

---------------------------------------- 
GO 

SELECT * FROM   #test_tran
```

And output is

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Divide by zero error encountered.

(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)

Completion time: 2020-07-12T12:39:16.9097805+03:00
```

Why transaction was not stopped when error occurred at DECLARE @a FLOAT = 1 / 0.0 ? Why insert into statement is executed after divide by zero exception thrown?

If I use BEGIN TRY BEGIN CATCH the exception is caught and it prevents inserting, but I want to understand why execution is continue after exception thrown.

Comment: some errors abort the batch, others just abort the statement. See http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/SQL2000-I.html#actions  for more on this. Use `xact_ abort` or try catch if you want the transaction rolled back on any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL exceptions don't behave quite the same way as they do in application code. They don't *always* cause the stack to unwind up to a catch block (or process termination) - unless you actually have a catch block.

in SQL, some errors will cause a whole batch to terminate, others may not - depending on the setting of [`xact_abort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15). Some information on this can be found the the remarks of [`raiserror`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

If the error has a `severity` greater than 10, and the error is *not* in a `try` block, then the client application will receive that error as part of an exception.

If the error as a `severity` greater than 20, the whole batch - and the connection - will terminate.

So, there are three ways to "detect" errors in TSQL:

1. Use a try/catch
2. Check the value of the `@@error` system variable after each statement.
3. If you always want to stop processing, then `set xact_abort on`